# How can I quickly switch between different formatter profiles in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am working in a codebase where there are two different code styles for Java files that I have to maintain. It is a pain to open up Preferences and switch the profile each time I change a file.

I cannot easily separate the different files into different projects.

Autodetecting which format a file uses would be even better.